# Why objects need heap memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, memory

I have a class named **class1**

```
public class class1
        {
            public int property1;
            public int property2;
            public int property3;
        }
```

there are two objects of Same class having same datatype and values (obj1 and obj2 have same types that is **class1** and have same values)

```
class1 obj1 = new class1();
            obj1.property1 = 12;
            obj1.property2 = 0;
            obj1.property3 = 18;

class1 obj2 = new class1();
            obj2.property1 = 12;
            obj2.property2 = 0;
            obj2.property3 = 18;
```

here I want to compare the objects of **class1** but this condition always returns false

```
if (obj1 == obj2)
            {

            }
            else
            { 

            }
```

after a research I found that this is due to Value type and reference types [A Value Type holds the data within its own memory allocation and a Reference Type contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the real data](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)

**My question is Why objects need heap memory ?**

Comment: pointer to object data is being kept in stack. Object data itself is being kept in heap.

Comment: _"My question is Why objects need heap memory ?"_ This question is better served by a good _Learning c# 101_ book or tutorial rather than this site

Comment: I think you are conflating different issues. It doesn't have to do with reference types or heap allocation. The meaning of `operator==` is a language choice, and different languages make different choices. C++ allows you to overload the operator, and it also has a concept of references as aliases to objects. So comparing two references in C++ is the same as comparing two objects.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'll say that C# references are more similar to C++ pointers... You can do a `List<object>` in C#, but in C++ you can't do a `vector<object&>` (and you can do a `vector<object*>`)

Comment: @xanatos Yes, I would agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the two objects like that. If you want to compare two object then you have to Implement `IEquatable<T>` interface.

Also note that all variables are members of a reference type (ie, your class), so they all will be on the heap. You should understand that the heap is used for storage of data where the lifetime for which the data will be stored cannot be predicted in advance.

Also read this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx) which describes it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: *You cannot compare the two objects like that. If you want to compare two object then you have to Implement IEquatable<T> interface.* This is wrong. He has to create an `operator==` that does what he wants, *or* (normally *and*) overload the `Equals(object)` method. The `IEquatable<T>` is totally optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (obj1 == obj2)
```

You are comparing the reference type, it will return false because it compare 2 pointer.
If you wanna use this operator, implement `IComparable<class1>` and these methods:

```
 public class Class1 : IComparable<Class1> {
     public static bool operator ==(Class1 a, Class1 b) {
          //define when a == b, compare property1, 2, ect...
     }
     public static bool operator !=(Class1 a, Class1 b){
          //define when a != b, compare property1, 2, ect...
     }
 }
```

You define how to compare this class by this operator. Ex: Compare property1,property2,ect...